# Previouls Daily Close

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have a dataframe of intraday data and I would like to get the previous daily close on the next day of intraday bar data.  My dataframe is uses a datetime index.

I don't seem to have a good way to do it.  i tried to resample the date and get the daily close and them merge into the other date frame but that wont work as the indexes and size are different.  IS there a way to do this using a vector approach via pandas?
THNX

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Vol Daily_Low   is_daily_low    PrevDayClose
datetime                                
2012-09-18 09:30:00 1324.25 1325.00 1321.75 1324.50 143720  1321.75 1   NaN
2012-09-18 10:00:00 1324.50 1325.50 1323.00 1324.25 96809   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 10:30:00 1324.25 1326.00 1323.50 1326.00 101617  1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 11:00:00 1326.00 1327.50 1325.25 1327.00 100908  1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 11:30:00 1326.75 1327.00 1324.25 1325.00 64223   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 12:00:00 1324.75 1325.25 1322.25 1322.50 60017   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 12:30:00 1322.50 1325.00 1322.25 1324.00 36732   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 13:00:00 1324.00 1325.00 1322.00 1323.75 50707   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 13:30:00 1323.75 1324.00 1322.50 1322.75 26744   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 14:00:00 1322.75 1324.25 1322.25 1323.75 33473   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 14:30:00 1323.50 1324.25 1322.50 1323.25 34082   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 15:00:00 1323.25 1325.00 1323.00 1324.25 34119   1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-18 15:30:00 1324.25 1325.75 1323.25 1325.50 117758  1321.75 0   NaN
2012-09-19 09:30:00 1327.50 1327.50 1323.50 1324.50 147406  1323.50 1   NaN
2012-09-19 10:00:00 1324.50 1329.25 1324.50 1326.75 148099  1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 10:30:00 1326.50 1327.25 1324.25 1326.25 106183  1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 11:00:00 1326.25 1330.25 1325.75 1329.50 130089  1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 11:30:00 1329.50 1330.25 1328.50 1329.25 61245   1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 12:00:00 1329.25 1331.25 1328.25 1331.00 91314   1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 12:30:00 1330.75 1331.25 1329.75 1330.25 32613   1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 13:00:00 1330.50 1330.75 1328.75 1329.00 24016   1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 13:30:00 1329.00 1330.00 1328.00 1329.00 29070   1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 14:00:00 1328.75 1330.50 1328.75 1329.75 20754   1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 14:30:00 1329.50 1330.75 1329.25 1330.75 25555   1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 15:00:00 1330.50 1331.25 1329.50 1329.75 49683   1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-19 15:30:00 1329.75 1330.00 1326.50 1326.50 138803  1323.50 0   NaN
2012-09-20 09:30:00 1320.00 1321.00 1315.75 1316.75 192555  1315.75 1   NaN
2012-09-20 10:00:00 1317.00 1321.00 1316.50 1320.25 163925  1315.75 0   NaN
2012-09-20 10:30:00 1320.00 1323.50 1319.75 1323.25 114184  1315.75 0   NaN
2012-09-20 11:00:00 1323.25 1324.50 1321.25 1322.25 126658  1315.75 0   NaN
```

I want to take this a make a column that is the close form the previous day that is forward filled from the previous day. SO, in my case, the data the previous close column should forward fill from 15:30 Close on 9/18/2012 until the next next day on 9/19/2012.  9/20 should have the column filled for hte next day with the previous day close.

Comment: `pandas.Series.shift(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should show the structure of your dataframe to make it easy for others to make answer more relevant.

Anyway, you can use pandas groupby to group by date and then use last() to get 'close' for the given day..followed by shift(-1) to get previous days's close.

Edit:
Since yo won't share data structure, I am going to assume one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Price'], index = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H'))
df.Price = range(72)
df['PrevClose']= df.Price.groupby(df.index.date).last().shift(1)
df['PrevClose'] = df['PrevClose'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Edit #2:
get previous close:

```
g = df.groupby(df.index.date).close.last().shift(1)
```

apply to new columns:

```
df['daily_close'] = df.apply(lambda x: g.at[x.name.date()], axis=1)
```

Comment: yeah I tried that and it doesnt work.   I tried.. df1['PrevDayClose']=pd.groupby(df1.index.date)['Close].last().shift(1)

Comment: See my edit. Hopefully, this guides you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
df['daily_close'] = df.Close.groupby(df.index.date).last().shift().reindex(df.index.date).values